# Validating an autocomplete selection on a ko observable value

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have an autocomplete list of values. The selected value of this selection is a ko observed variable. I need to validate the value they selected from the list or the value they typed in, incase they did not select a value from the list.

It appears right now that when they type a letter and then select a value from the list, the validation call is fired for the letter they typed and then its called at the same time for the value they selected.

Is there a good approach to validating the value the user selected or typed where I do not get this race condition?

Here is some code:

HTML

```
<div>
                            <label for="AssignedTo">Assigned To: </label>
                            <input id="AssignedTo" placeholder="Assigned To" data-bind="ko_autocomplete:{source: $parent.users(), select: addAssignedTo}, value: AssignedTo"/>
                            <span class="error" data-bind="text: AssignedToInvalid"></span>
                        </div>
```

MODEL

```
self.AssignedToInvalid= ko.observable();
    self.AssignedTo= ko.observable();
    self.addAssignedTo= function (event, ui) {
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(self.AssignedTo())) {
            IsUserValid(ui.item.label, self.AssignedToValidated, self.AssignedToNotValid);
        }
    };

self.AssignedToValidated= function (user) {
        self.AssignedTo(user);
    };

    self.AssignedToNotValid= function (error) {
        self.AssignedToInvalid("Invalid user");
    };

    self.AssignedTo.subscribe(function() {
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(self.AssignedTo)) {
            IsUserValid(self.AssignedTo(), self.AssignedToValidated, self.AssignedToNotValid);
        }
    });
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function IsUserValid(userName, successFunc, failureFunc) {
    var url = '/Controller/Method';
    var data = [{ name: 'userName', value: userName}];
    PostJson(url, data, successFunc, failureFunc);
}
```

KO Binding Handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ko_autocomplete = {
    init: function (element, params) {
        $(element).autocomplete(params());
    },
    update: function (element, params) {
        $(element).autocomplete("option", "source", params().source);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I see `IsUserValid` being updated, but it is not used or created anywhere.  What is that and what is it for?  It seems to be a critical part of your code, but I have no idea what it is supposed to be doing.  Also, please tell us what `ko_autocomplete` is.

Comment: I went ahead and posted them but I didnt before because they are not vital. I want to know how to validate a click of the autocomplete as well as if they just type the username avoiding the race condition that I currently have with the subscribe and add function.